# ColdFusion 11 - Cannot configure IIS connector

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I try CF 2016, but keep on giving me: Cannot configure IIS connector. Enable the required options ASP.NET, CGI, IAAPI Extensions....

CF 2016 on Windows 10 64 bit machine

Cannot configure IIS connector. Enable the required options ASP.NET, CGI, IAAPI Extensions

Comment: Seems more like a Windows Server issue. First step would be going to the Server Manager -> Add Roles & Features.

Comment: Did you enable those required options?

Answer (score 8):

1. Open the Control Panel, and click on the Programs and Features icon.
2. Click on the Turn Windows features on or off link on the left side.
3. Expand "Internet Information Services"
4. Expand "World Wide Web Services"
5. Expand "Application Development Features"
6. Check the boxes to enable the features you mention in your question (see picture)
7. Click OK, after that you might have to restart your computer and re-install CF

[image]